# Unable to send attached file to E-Mail

Tags: php, email

I am trying to send attach file to email. But i am unable to send the attach file along with the form data to email. I tried

HTML:

```
        <form action="sendmail.php" method="post" name="form1" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <table width="343" border="1">
        <tr>
        <td>Name</td>
        <td><input name="name" type="text" id="name"></td> 
    </tr> 
    <tr>
        <td>City</td>
        <td><input name="city" type="text" id="city"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Descibe Yourself</td>
        <td><textarea name="description" cols="30" rows="4" id="description"></textarea></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Mobile Number</td>
        <td><input name="mobile" id="mobile"type="text"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Email</td>
        <td><input name="email" type="email" id="email"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Attach Your Image</td>
      <td><input name="fileAttach" type="file"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Send"></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    </form>
```

sendmail.php:

```
    <?
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $city = $_POST['city'];
    $description = $_POST['description'];
    $mobile = $_POST['mobile'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];

    if ($name == '' || $city == '' || $description==''|| $mobile=='' || $email=='')
                    {
                echo "<script> alert('Fill all fields, try again!');
                window.location='contact.html'</script>";
                exit;
                }


    $ToEmail = 'info@mywebsite.com'; 
    $EmailSubject = 'Website contact form'; 
    $mailheader = "From: ".$_POST["email"]."\r\n"; 
    $mailheader .= "Reply-To: ".$_POST["email"]."\r\n"; 
    $mailheader .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n"; 
    $MESSAGE_BODY = "Name: ".$_POST["name"]."<br><br>"; 
    $MESSAGE_BODY .= "Email: ".$_POST["email"]."<br>"; 
    $MESSAGE_BODY .= "Description: ".$_POST["description"]."<br>"; 
    $MESSAGE_BODY .= "Mobile: ".nl2br($_POST["mobile"])."<br>";
    $MESSAGE_BODY .= "City: ".nl2br($_POST["city"])."<br>";


    //*** Attachment ***//
    if($_FILES["fileAttach"]["name"] != "")
    {
        $strFilesName = $_FILES["fileAttach"]["name"];
        $strContent = chunk_split(base64_encode(file_get_contents($_FILES["fileAttach"]["tmp_name"]))); 
        $strHeader .= "--".$strSid."\n";
        $strHeader .= "Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name=\"".$strFilesName."\"\n"; 
        $strHeader .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n";
        $strHeader .= "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$strFilesName."\"\n\n";
        $strHeader .= $strContent."\n\n";
    }


     mail($ToEmail, $EmailSubject, $MESSAGE_BODY, $mailheader, $strHeader) or die ("Failure");
    echo "<script> alert('Messgae successfully sent!');
    window.location='index.html'</script>";
       exit; 



    if($mail)
    {
        echo "<script> alert('Messgae successfully sent!');
    window.location='index.html'</script>";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "<script> alert('Temporary problem, try again!');</script>";
    }
?>
```

I tried the same code without $strHeader in mail() the mail was sent but when i added $strHeader to mail() i was unable to send code. Kindly guide me where i am doing mistake and also plz tell how how can i allow only jpg,jpeg,png format to to uploaded. Edited code for me would be easy for me for learning. I checked lot of answers on stackoverflow bt couldn't found the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try using \r\n instead of \n ...

```
$strHeader .= "--".$strSid."\r\n";
$strHeader .= "Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name=\"".$strFilesName."\"\r\n"; 
$strHeader .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n";
$strHeader .= "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$strFilesName."\"\r\n\r\n";
$strHeader .= $strContent."\r\n\r\n";
```

## EDIT

Change:

```
$mailheader = "From: ".$_POST["email"]."\r\n"; 
$mailheader .= "Reply-To: ".$_POST["email"]."\r\n"; 
$mailheader .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n"; 
$MESSAGE_BODY = "Name: ".$_POST["name"]."<br><br>"; 
$MESSAGE_BODY .= "Email: ".$_POST["email"]."<br>"; 
$MESSAGE_BODY .= "Description: ".$_POST["description"]."<br>"; 
$MESSAGE_BODY .= "Mobile: ".nl2br($_POST["mobile"])."<br>";
$MESSAGE_BODY .= "City: ".nl2br($_POST["city"])."<br>";
```

With:

```
$hash   = md5(date('r', time()));
$mailheader = "From: {$_POST["email"]}\r\n"; 
$mailheader .= "Reply-To: {$_POST["email"]}\r\n"; 
$mailheader .= "Content-type: text/html; boundary=\"PHP-mixed-$hash\""; 
$MESSAGE_BODY = "Name: {$_POST["name"]}<br><br>"; 
$MESSAGE_BODY .= "Email: {$_POST["email"]}<br>"; 
$MESSAGE_BODY .= "Description: {$_POST["description"]}<br>"; 
$MESSAGE_BODY .= "Mobile: ".nl2br($_POST["mobile"])."<br>";
$MESSAGE_BODY .= "City: ".nl2br($_POST["city"])."<br>";
```

---

And change

```
$strFilesName = $_FILES["fileAttach"]["name"];
$strContent = chunk_split(base64_encode(file_get_contents($_FILES["fileAttach"]["tmp_name"]))); 
$strHeader .= "--".$strSid."\n";
$strHeader .= "Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name=\"".$strFilesName."\"\n"; 
$strHeader .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n";
$strHeader .= "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$strFilesName."\"\n\n";
$strHeader .= $strContent."\n\n";
```

With

```
$strFilesName = $_FILES["fileAttach"]["name"];
$strContent = chunk_split(base64_encode(file_get_contents($_FILES["fileAttach"]["tmp_name"]))); 
$MESSAGE_BODY .= "--PHP-mixed-$hash\r\n";
$MESSAGE_BODY .= "Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name=\"$strFilesName\"\r\n";
$MESSAGE_BODY .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n";
$MESSAGE_BODY .= "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$strFilesName\"\r\n\r\n";
$MESSAGE_BODY .= $strContent."\r\n";
$MESSAGE_BODY .= "--PHP-mixed-$hash--";
```

You missed the boundary.

Comment: i tried but failed to send data in mail

Comment: changed the code but didnt wrk. Please check all the code ad please edit it for me, i am finding it difficult to complete this. please help me

Answer (score 0):

This has been already answered.
Check out [form not sending image file to email](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31533174/form-not-sending-image-file-to-email)
and my comment to send email with attachment.